# Getting error of timeout exceed in mocha

Tags: node.js, http, promise, timeout, mocha.js

mocha error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded, for async test and hooks ensure the done() callback is being called in this test. if returning a promise, ensure it resolves.

This is what  the error i am getting while trying to get response,

This is my index.js file where i export function

```
exports.info = function(callback) { 
    var https = require('https'); 
    var options = {
     host: 'api.github.com', 
     path: '/repos/sayanee/build-podcast', 
     method: 'GET', 
     headers: { 'User-Agent': 'sayanee' } }; 
    var str = '';

    https.request(options, function(response) { 
    response.on('data', function(data) { 
        str += data; 
    });

     response.on('end', function() {
       callback(JSON.parse(str));
     })

     response.on('error', function(error) {
       console.log(error);
       callback();
    })    
})    .end();
}
```

This is my indexfile where i describe the test cases

```
function asyncFunction() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, 5000);
    });
}
describe('Github info', function() {
it.only('returns repo info from github', async function() { 
    //this.timeout(5000);
    await asyncFunction();
    word.info(function(reply) { 
        console.log("er")
        expect(reply.language).to.equal('JavaScript'); 
        expect(reply.watchers).to.equal(157); 
        console.log('RECEIVED'); 

    }); 
    console.log('HELLO'); })
});
```

Comment: Have you tried uncomment `this.timeout(5000)`?

Comment: @ponury-kostek I tried with that too, still i m not getting the respective json i am expecting inside the word.info function(reply)

Comment: Comment or remove `await asyncFunction();` or lower timeout value inside

Comment: @ponury-kostek if i remove await asynFunction() i am not getting any error and also i am not getting the respective json 'reply'

Comment: you could try enclosing expectation within `setTimeout`. Also, you either need to call `done()` or `return` from `it` block. check @ponury-kostek comment below

Comment: @HarshalGangurde Gangurde instead of done() callback i have tried async and await...

Answer (score 1):

Mocha support async test also by passing `done` callback as param to `it` that you need to call at test end

```
describe("Github info", function () {
    it.only("returns repo info from github", function (done) {
        // set long timeout to be sure word.info finish 
        this.timeout(5000);
        word.info(function (reply) {
            console.log("er");
            expect(reply.language).to.equal("JavaScript");
            expect(reply.watchers).to.equal(157);
            console.log("RECEIVED");
            // call done at end
            done();
        });
        console.log("HELLO");
    });
});
```

Comment: this was the code at first, i got the error i have shared at the top and so tried with async and await and ended up with the same...

Answer (score 0):

The response is in your question. `Mocha` is setted up to timeout after *2 second.*

---

Either you makes your request to finish within *2000ms*

---

Either you increase the [Mocha timeout](https://mochajs.org/#usage), *example :*

```
mocha -t 300000
```

---

---

**EDIT** :

You cannot use `async/await` mixed up with `callbacks`

```
// Wrap your function into a promise
wordInfoPromise() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    word.info((ret) => {
      if (!ret) return reject();

      return resolve(ret);
    });
  });
}
```

---

```
it('returns repo info from github', async function() { 
    //this.timeout(5000);
    await asyncFunction();

    const reply = await wordInfoPromise();

    console.log("er")

    expect(reply.language).to.equal('JavaScript'); 

    expect(reply.watchers).to.equal(157); 

    console.log('RECEIVED'); 

    console.log('HELLO'); })
});
```

---

---

EDIT 2 :

```
    const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
      res.on('data', (d) => {
        str += data;
      });

      res.on('end', () => {
        resolve(str);
      });
    });

    req.on('error', (e) => {
      reject();
    });

    req.end();
```

Comment: I am not getting that after i resolved promise using async and await , still i am not getting the json i expected to get instead just getting passing status alone. none of the console is getting printed.

Comment: exactly done what u said but still getting the same error -  timeout of 2000ms exceeded, for async test and hooks ensure the done() callback is being called in this test. if returning a promise, ensure it r

Comment: try by calling it using `mocha -t 30000` to see if this is the request that makes more than 2s to resolve

Comment: Tried doing so getting error: connect ETIMEDOUT 192.30.253.117:443

Comment: So my guess is that `exports.info` do not work properly. Look at your request to see if it's good. I've made a second edit

Comment: NEUT yeah exports .info is not working properly even a static console.log inside http.request is not getting displayed